# Bash Diff of Nested Files

Tags: json, bash, diff

**Premise**:

I have **five** files in **two** directories.

```
folder/
├─ old/
│  ├─ a.json
│  ├─ b.xml
├─ new/
│  ├─ a.json
│  ├─ b.xml
│  ├─ c.html
```

**old/a.json**

```json
{
   "hello": {
   },
   "world": ""
}
```

**new/a.json**

```json
{
   "hello": {},
   "world": ""
}
```

**old/b.xml** and **new/b.xml** are the same.

When I run `diff` I get:

```
2,3c2
<       "hello": {
<       }, 
---
>       "hello": {},
```

As well as the new file, **c.html**.

---

**Solution**:

I want to only see that `c.html` is the new file added. I want to ignore the newline/spaces in the two `a.json`.

Ideally I'd like to do `diff -I '${REGEX_HERE}' folder/old folder/new` to accomplish this. Is this possible? I also have other bash utilities at my disposal. This is meant to run in a Dockerfile.

Comment: Did you try `diff -w` to ignore all spaces?

Comment: @NoDataFound diff is line-based, so that doesn't help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `jq` on each json file to produce a common format of output then `diff` THAT:

```
diff <(jq . folder/old/a.json) <(jq . folder/new/a.json)
```

For example:

```
$ head *.json
==> x.json <==
{
   "hello": {
   },
   "world": ""
}

==> y.json <==
{
   "hello": {},
   "world": ""
}
```

```
$ jq . x.json
{
  "hello": {},
  "world": ""
}

$ jq . y.json
{
  "hello": {},
  "world": ""
}
```

```
$ diff <(jq . x.json) <(jq . y.json)
$
```

To do what you asked for `I want to ignore the newline/spaces in the two a.json` would be:

```
$ diff <(tr -d '[[:space:]]' < x.json) <(tr -d '[[:space:]]' < y.json)
$
```

but that assumes your version of `diff` works on input files that don't have a terminating newline and so aren't valid text files per POSIX, and that you're OK with ALL white space being removed, even inside quotes, and that you don't care about other layout differences between the 2 files.

I expect you'll run into the same problem of wanting to ignore **some** of the white space and/or other formatting possibilities in xml and other files so you'd have to write a tool something like this to be able to diff the 2 directories as you appear to want (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -d '' files < <(find folder -type f -printf '%P\0' | sort -zu)

diffByType() {
    case $1 in
        *.json ) diff <(jq . "$1") <(jq . "$2") >&2 ;;
        *.xml )  diff <(xmlstarlet fo "$1") <(xmlstarlet fo "$2") >&2 ;;
        * )      diff "$1" "$2" >&2 ;;
    esac
    return
}

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ -f "folder/old/$file" ]]; then
        if [[ -f "folder/new/$file" ]]; then
            if ! diffByType "folder/old/$file" "folder/new/$file"; then
                printf '%s is different\n' "$file" >&2
            fi
        else
            printf '%s is only in old\n' "$file" >&2
        fi
    else
        printf '%s is only in new\n' "$file" >&2
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**Posting my solution which is just an uglier version of the accepted answer:**

This was unsolvable in one line. I had to bring in more commands and work around the problem.

What I did was I formatted the `.json` files into `.pretty` files, then ignored the `.json` files that had been formatted (preserving the originals).

Finding and formatting the `.json` files:

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.json" -exec sh -c 'cat $0 | jq > $0.pretty' {} \;
```

Ignoring all the json files:

```bash
diff -r -x '*.json' old new
```

Gave me the result that I wanted.